# Angular, Keycloak and cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, keycloak

I have an angular application (i don't use ionic) that use keycloak authentication (keycloak-angular and keycloak-js).

I tries to create a mobile app of my application using apache cordova, but I'm blocked on the step of letting keycloak working in cordova.
For information, everything is configured well in keycloak (redirect uri ...).

My questions are the follows:

1. Is keycloak angular compatible with cordova ?
2. Is it possible to use my application in cordova without any changement for the authentication part or I should implement the authentication mechanism by myself (without using the keycloakAuthGuard).
3. Is it possible to display the keycloak authentication page directly in the app without opening the web navigator (Maybe with the plug-in inappbrowser)?
4. Is there are any complete example about integration of keycloak-angular and cordova?

Thanks in advance,
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

No I dont think you can use angular keycloak directly on cordova. But you can use inAppBrowser plugin to open keycloak authentication page outside app and then use deeplinks plugin to catch redirect url to your app and extract url params to use them to get authentication token.

Comment: There is also a possibility to open keycloak auth page inside app with iframe but using inAppBrowser is a better approach in my opinion.